loadMoreItems not triggering in react-window-infinite-loader with FixedSizeGrid
I have used react-window react-window package to implement virtualization and I am using <FixedSizeGrid> component for that along with <InfiniteLoader> from react-window-infinite-loader text.
But the problem is the loadMoreItems is not getting called. It is used properly as mentioned in its documentation. Also i have set limit=10 and threshold=5.
I tried implementing the infinite scroll using react-window-infinite-loader package. but as the loadMoreItems is not getting called the Infinite-Scroll is not happening.
Expected behaviour : loadMoreItems should be called everytime threshold hits so that the Infinite-Scrolling can be possible.
Below is the code for the scenario discussed.
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import { FixedSizeGrid } from 'react-window';
import InfiniteLoader from 'react-window-infinite-loader';
import AutoSizer from 'react-virtualized-auto-sizer';
import './store_projects.scss';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import useMediaQuery from '../../hooks/useMediaQuery';
import { StoreMediaQueries } from '../../constants';

const { mediaQueries } = StoreMediaQueries;

const VirtualizedInfiniteList = ({
  items,
  hasMore,
  loadMoreItems,
  threshold,
  children,
  isLoading,
}) => {
  const activeMediaQuery = useMediaQuery(mediaQueries);
  const { gridColumnCount = 1, gridRowHeight } = activeMediaQuery?.mediaQuery ?? {};

  const isItemLoaded = (index) => !hasMore || index < items.length;

  const loadMore = isLoading ? () => {} : loadMoreItems;

  const getIndexFromGridPosition = useCallback((col, row, columnCount) => {
    const index = (row * columnCount) + col;
    return index;
  }, []);

  const itemCount = hasMore ? Math.ceil(items.length / gridColumnCount) + 1 : items.length;

  return (
    <AutoSizer>
      {({ height, width }) => (
        <InfiniteLoader
          isItemLoaded={isItemLoaded}
          itemCount={itemCount}
          loadMoreItems={loadMore}
          threshold={threshold}
        >
          {({ onItemsRendered, ref }) => (
            <FixedSizeGrid
              className="virtualized-grid-wrapper"
              columnCount={gridColumnCount}
              columnWidth={width / gridColumnCount}
              height={height}
              ref={ref}
              rowCount={Math.ceil(items.length / gridColumnCount)}
              rowHeight={gridRowHeight}
              width={width}
              onItemsRendered={onItemsRendered}
            >
              {({ columnIndex, rowIndex, style }) => {
                const index = getIndexFromGridPosition(columnIndex, rowIndex, gridColumnCount);

                if (!items || items.length === 0 || index >= items.length) {
                  return null;
                }

                return (
                  <div className="store-project-card-wrapper" style={style}>
                    {children(items[index])}
                  </div>
                );
              }}
            </FixedSizeGrid>
          )}
        </InfiniteLoader>
      )}
    </AutoSizer>
  );
};

VirtualizedInfiniteList.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.shape([]).isRequired,
  hasMore: PropTypes.bool,
  loadMoreItems: PropTypes.func,
  threshold: PropTypes.number,
  children: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isLoading: PropTypes.bool,
};

VirtualizedInfiniteList.defaultProps = {
  hasMore: false,
  loadMoreItems: () => {},
  threshold: 5,
  isLoading: false,
};

export default VirtualizedInfiniteList;

LoadMoreItems function :
  const loadMoreItems = useCallback(() => {
    if (!isLoading && hasMore) {
      setProject((prev) => ({ ...prev, isLoading: true }));
      fetchMore({
        variables: {
          limit: allProjectsLimit,
          offset: list.length,
        },
        updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult: { filterProjectsForAdmin: storeProjects } }) => {
          if (!storeProjects.length) {
            return prev;
          }

          setProject((prevProjects) => ({
            list: [...prevProjects.list, ...storeProjects],
            hasMore: storeProjects.length >= allProjectsLimit,
            isLoading: false,
          }));
          return null;
        },
      });
    }
  }, [fetchMore, hasMore, isLoading, list.length]);

